# Open pdf file using WebView with Basic Authorization

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, basic-authentication

> This is my complete code for getting pdf file using WebView and BasicAuthentication

```
public class ShowPdf extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "ShowPdf: ";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
String pdf = "";
private final String HOST = Cons.BASE_URL;
private final String URL = "http://" + HOST + "/";
private final String USERNAME = Cons.USERNAME;
private final String PASSWORD = Cons.PASSWORD;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
WebView webview;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_pdf, container, false);
    sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Cons.MyPREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    webview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Bundle bundle= this.getArguments();
    if (bundle.containsKey("pdf_url")){
        pdf= bundle.getString("pdf_url");
    }
    setBasicAuth();
    webview.loadUrl(pdf);

    return view;

}
protected void setBasicAuth() {
    WebViewDatabase.getInstance(getActivity()).clearHttpAuthUsernamePassword();
    webview.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(HOST, HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
            String[] up = view.getHttpAuthUsernamePassword(host, realm);
            handler.proceed(sharedPreferences.getString(Cons.USERNAME, ""), sharedPreferences.getString(Cons.PASSWORD, ""));
            if (up != null && up.length == 2) {
                handler.proceed(up[0], up[1]);
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not find username/password for domain: " + host + ", with realm = " + realm);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

> Now plz can you explain what i am doing wrong here. and Log is not printing in Logcat.
>
> it logcat data

```
E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
```

E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008d57
E/DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp

Answer (score 1):

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "pdf_url_path";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

try using like this

Comment: i want to send **Username - Password** too

Comment: do u mean user name and password to access the pdf file or the username and password for the drive

Comment: u ve to pass a url of the pdf to the location where it is stored

Answer (score 1):

A WebView cannot display a pdf file.

So its unclear what you have in mind with that file.

Comment: i just want to display a pdf file without downloading. To get file from server REST Api requires BasicAuthentication. thats it.

Comment: If the file is on the web you have to download it first of course. But having downloaded a pdf file WebView will not be able to display it. As webview cannot display pdf files. Thats it. You should come to the point with your pdf. And with what you want. Thats it.

Comment: is there any other way to display a pdf file??

Comment: Other answers suggest you are using google docs. Until now you did not confirm or deny. Please give decent info as all this takes a lot of time in this way.

Comment: i already told that i just want  to show a pdf file , which I am getting from URL, but that URL requires BASIC AUTHENTICATION to access. if BasicAuthentication is removed from accessing that pdf file  then i can easily access  it using Google Drive. But RestApi requires BasicAuthentication to open that file. And BasicAuthentication is my problem  becoz am not able to send that with url while accessing pdf file.

Comment: If you want to download a file from google drive then you should have started your post with it to begin with. So now you are telling that google docs has nothing to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Add given function to your code...

```
protected void setBasicAuth() {
        WebViewDatabase.getInstance(this).clearHttpAuthUsernamePassword();
        webview.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(HOST, HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
                String[] up = view.getHttpAuthUsernamePassword(host, realm);
                handler.proceed(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                if (up != null && up.length == 2) {
                    handler.proceed(up[0], up[1]);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("", "Could not find username/password for domain: " + host + ", with realm = " + realm);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

and call it before `webview.loadUrl(URL);`

where some fields are...

```
private final String HOST = "basic-auth-sample.com";
private final String URL = "http://" + HOST + "/";
private final String USERNAME = "user";
private final String PASSWORD = "pass";
```

let me know if any query there...

Happy coding.

Comment: what is **HOST** here webview.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(HOST, HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

Comment: @Imransamed updated answer. please accept if it works

Comment: need to use host two times???    webview.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(HOST, HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

Comment: void setHttpAuthUsernamePassword (String host, 
                String realm, 
                String username, 
                String password)

Comment: what value you have taken for HOST?

Answer (score 0):

webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + yoururl);